# PHP unexpected operator evaluation

Tags: php, operators

I faced this strange PHP operator evaluation, and I cannot see why this happens

```
$By=0.52;
$Vi=38;
$Bx= 37.48;
$Zi=0;
var_dump($By >= ($Vi-$Bx-$Zi));
```

I get

```
boolean false
```

but since

```
$By = 0.52
$Vi-$Bx-$Zi = 0.52
```

so `$By >= ($Vi-$Bx-$Zi)`
should be `true`, because the operator is ">="
as in php doc `$a >= $b Greater than or equal to    TRUE if $a is greater than or equal to $b.`

why this happens?

```
var dump
array(7) {
  ["$Bx"]=>
  float(37.48)
  ["($Vi-$Zi)"]=>
  int(38)
  ["$By"]=>
  float(0.52)
  ["($Vi-$Bx-$Zi)"]=>
  float(0.52)
  ["$Bx<($Vi-$Zi)"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["$By>=($Vi-$Bx-$Zi)"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["($Bx<($Vi-$Zi) && $By>=($Vi-$Bx-$Zi))"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Could be an issue with [floating point accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems): `echo number_format($Vi-$Bx-$Zi, 16);` gives `0.5200000000000031`

Comment: It is about float comparison, read this [link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch02_03.htm) and this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de